# iio-sensor-proxy does not detect any sensor

Tags: sensors

I recently switched to Ubuntu to make full use of my HP Envy x360 flipbook. I was planning to use iio-sensor-proxy to detect the screen flipping, but it does not work.

When, following the instructions on here: https://github.com/haDescription: Ubuntu 19.04
dess/iio-sensor-proxy I run `udevadm info --export-db` no iio device appears on the list.

The command 
`gdbus introspect --system --dest net.hadess.SensorProxy --object-path /net/hadess/SensorProxy` 
produces the following error message:

```
Error: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name net.hadess.SensorProxy was not provided by any .service files
```

I'm currently running Ubuntu 19.04 with kernel 5.0.0-15-generic

Any pointers?

Answer (score 0):

Right now there isn't a fix for this, because it is a driver level issue. I just learned from [Phoronix](https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=AMD-SFH-Linux-V2) that the new driver will be released probably with the new 5.6/5.7 Kernel, which is approaching completion now. 
Obviously this affects only people who have HP Envy models with AMD APU's.
We just have to wait until the release of the new Kernel.

Comment: Do you know if there's any update on that? I couldn't find any news on the subject

Comment: @IncrediblyConvoluted Last time I checked out, the drivers were not ready for kernel 5.8/5.9 I think next year we will see something

Comment: @IncrediblyConvoluted [Here](https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=AMD-SFH-For-Linux-5.11) the article that confirms that the module will arrive with kernel 5.11, we just need to wait.